# Access applet methods via javascript in IE7

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer-7, applet

I've got an applet that runs fine in firefox, however in ie8 (and ie7 I think), the javascript doesn't seem to be able to access the applets methods.

in the js debugger -

```
scanApplet.addUploadParameter
```

gives me a java exception -

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: addUploadParameter in class: co.altcom.cache.scanner.CacheScan
```

The (jquery) code I'm actually trying to run is

```
$('input, select').each(function () {
    scanApplet.addUploadParameter(this.name, this.value);
});
```

Which is throwing the following java exception -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I don't really know where to start with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't include it in my question but I was creating the scanApplet variable using jquery -

```
var scanApplet = $('#scanApplet')[0]
```

It looks like it was the `scanApplet` variable that was the problem. The following code fixes the problem.

```
        $('input, select').each(function () {
            var el_name = $(this).prop('name');
            var el_value = $(this).val();
            if (Browser.Version() < 8) {
                scanApplet.addUploadParameter(el_name, el_value);
            } else {
                $('#scanApplet')[0].addUploadParameter(el_name, el_value);
            }
        });
```

I've no idea why ie7 allows me to reference the applet like this, there's no assignment to scanApplet in my code - I guess it's something to do with the way java's deployJava.js deals with ie, but I never found any documentation about it. I'm deploying the applet using the following -

```
        var attributes = {id: 'scanApplet', code: "{{ jar_path }}",  width:1, height:1} ;
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: "{{ jnlp_path }}"} ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
```

Neither have I got any idea what broke my code, I think I've changed the versions of jquery I've been using but I tried quickly swapping out 1.6.1 for 1.4.2 and that didn't fix my orginal code.

Anyway referencing the applet by it's id seems to fix my issues in ie7.

Answer (score 2):

Within the `each` you should use the `this` keyword wrapped in the jQuery function. In addition, for name you can use the [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) function, and for value there's the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. So the jQuery would be:

```
$('input, select').each(function () {  
    scanApplet.addUploadParameter($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val());  
});
```

That should fix the JavaScript bit. Without more info I can't tell if it fixes *all* your problems, and whether it fixes the Java error, so get back to us with more info if you still need more help after this.

**Edit**
In the comments it's mentioned IE7 still give problems. You should be debugging the call in IE7 then to see which bit of the code is giving you trouble. A *quick, oldskool and **very dirty*** way would be to just log or alert things to see where the problem is. E.g.:

```
    // scanApplet.addUploadParameter($(this).prop('name'), $(this).val());
    alert(scanApplet);
    alert(scanApplet.addUploadParameter);
    alert($(this).prop('name'));
    // etc etc
```

Comment: This is strange. My coding is failing again with the same error. I've stumbled across my original question while trying to debug. Everything is as above (with Jeroen's changes), but I'm getting the java.lang.NullPointerException again. (actually ie8 is working ok, it's just ie7 that fails)

Comment: You should be debugging what happens in your JS in IE7 then. I've added a quick and dirty way to do that in my answer.

Comment: Also, don't forget to get back to this question and tell us what your solution was (either edit my answer and accept it, or create your own answer and accept it). That way if anyone else stumbles here he/she will be able to find the final solution.

Comment: I may wait a bit longer before accepting anything - it may be others can shed more light on the issue. Also I ended up installing visual studios express to debug ie7. Thanks again for all your input.